# Add JHipster child entity from parent entity detail page

Tags: jhipster

I am developing a JHipster application, in which I have the `Book` entity and the `Chapter` entity.

I would like to be able to add a `Chapter` to a `Book` from the `Book` detail page, rather than having to:

1. go to the `Chapter`s list
2. choose to add a new `Chapter`
3. select the appropriate `Book` in the popup

Can this type of behaviour be generated automatically or do I need to do it by hand?

Comment: You must do it  by hand